# How to avoid focus going to tabbable items in a minimized chat component

Tags: angular, accessibility, chatbot

I have a chat component which gets loaded in a side bar component when we click on chat icon on the site header. I need to make it accessible and hence I added tabindex = 0 to all important pieces such as minimize icon and close icon on chat container and all the chat messages. Now when I open chat once and then again close or minimize it, these elements still come in tabing order and the screen reader reads them. How can I prevent focus going on these elements when the chat is minimized/closed?

Answer (score 1):

The invisible part of web components should be hidden using the `display: none` CSS property to prevent both the keyboard focus to tab to them and the visual focus to make the screenreader read them.